# Some Windows System files cannot be deleted

Tags: windows

When I used to be a kid instead of formatting I used to delete everything in my hard-disk.

When try to delete all the files from my Windows installed hard-drive some system files remains un-deleted. Even after installing another fresh copy of Windows (without formatting the drive) the files remain there un-deleted and when I try to manually delete them the system says "access denied" (don't remember the error message).

How can I delete these system Files ?

Comment: You are very inquisitive today, @Subanki!

Comment: @JNK yup i am my professor says "never leave behind any doubts"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although formatting the hard drive before an installation of a new Operating System is best and I highly recommend it, you can delete files that windows doesn't want deleted by taking ownership of the file and then deleting it.  This is how you take ownership of a file:

> - Right click the file, select properties, and then the security tab.
> - Select then Advanced at the bottom of the window and then the tab owner.
> - Select Edit and then select the user you want to give permission to (either yourself or administrators)
> - Select Apply and then ok. Select ok and everything else so that all dialog boxes are closed.
> - Bring up the properties of the file again, and then select edit.
> - Select either the Users group or the Adminstrators group according to what you selected earlier.
> - Click the box below "Allow" and next to "Full Control"
>
> You can then delete the files necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend booting from a different disk (CD/DVD or external drive) then you can access the internal hard drive and do as you see fit without windows complaining that files are in use or locked.